# per-requisites listed against each of the A.I. field

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Yes A.I. field is very vast field. I have gone through the wiki page of A.I. and read about the different fields of it. I think any enthusiastic beginner can choose one of those fields based on his/her interest to get into A.I. But before getting in it is always good to have the per-requisites of the appropriate field.

It is very useful to have those per-requisites listed against each of the A.I. field to any beginner of A.I (like me) so that he can refresh his knowledge in them once and get started in actual field. Do someone list them here please?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot simply *refresh* or *brush up* knowledge in statistics, information theory, graph theory, complexity theory, topology, mathematical optimization, differential calculus, algebraic geometry, calculus of variations, spherical trigonometry, geodesy, game theory and various engineering disciplines. AI, in all its fields, requires pretty much learning at a new level.

This said, would prefer if you told us more about your particular background. How proficient are you in data structures and algorithms? What do you consider the most advanced math/stats book read so far?

Comment: As a minimum, please read as an introduction Stuart Russell's and Peter Norvig's Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach (1995). It is not that much modern any more, but may help in understanding what pre-requisites you still miss.

Comment: @DeerHunter - Thanks for the comments. I am a graduate in Mathamatics and Statistics (finished 12 years back). Working as a Programmer. Honestly I have not read any math/stat related book recently. By your comments I got that first I should go through the Peter Norvig's AI book and learn the required things at the time I g o through the AI fields subject.

Comment: Yup, that's the gist. Since you are for the most part at this side of the learning fence, you have to be more specific on the field of your choice. There are much better books than Norvig if you pose the question narrowly enough (on driverless cars/UAVs/USVs etc., or on machine learning...). There are also complete series (Springer's Lecture Notes in AI) that may be browsed in a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question does not have a simple answer. The degree of knowledge required depends on how in depth you want to go into the applicable field.

To use a simple neural network API for example, there are hardly any prerequisites. To know whether a neural network will work for a specific problem or to write your own neural network, you will need to have at least high-school level maths knowledge to understand the internals and thus limitations of a neural network (or you can try to memorize it all). To be able to argue and understand arguments of specific approaches, you will probably need college level maths.

If you want to learn more about AI and the different fields therein (and get some idea of the requirements), I suggest you take an introductory AI course or a course in the sub-field that interests you. Coursera.org is a decent site for such courses (and it's free). Many courses will give you a list of prerequisites before you sign up.

From my experience, the main prerequisites to many of the fields of AI are Statistics, Linear Algebra or Calculus.

A decent understanding of data structures and algorithms is also very important for most fields of AI (and programming in general).

I think rather than having someone put a giant table of all the prerequisites here, just select a sub-field that seems interesting, take an introductory course, and see if you understand it. You can always learn the prerequisites.

If you don't have high-school maths knowledge, it might be a good idea to start with a maths course or two before you think about AI.